# AngularJS + Mocha: How to test asynchronous script loading with promise?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, mocha.js

I have a util class with a load function which asynchronously loads the specified Google Maps library:

```
'use strict';
require('es6-promise').polyfill();
declare let window: any;

class GoogleMapsUtil {
  loadLibrary(args) {
    const KEY = 'SOME_KEY';
    const URL = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?';
    const LIBRARY = args.library;
    const v = args.v;
    let promise = Promise;

    if (!promise) {
      promise = require('es6-promise').Promise
    }

    return new promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
      element.type = 'text/javascript';
      element.async = true;
      element.defer = true;
      element.onload = () => {
        resolve(window.google);
      };
      element.onerror = () => {
        reject(new Error('Could not load the library'));
      };
      let params = [];
      params.push('key=' + KEY);
      params.push('v=' + v);
      params.push('libraries=' + LIBRARY);
      element.src = URL + params.join('&');
      document.body.appendChild(scriptElement);
    });
  }
};

export default GoogleMapsUtil;
```

I want to write a unit test that asserts that the returned promise is resolved with the asynchronously loaded library which should be a mock because I don't want to make a real http call in the test, but I'm not sure how to do this. Here's what I have so far:

```
import GoogleMapsUtil from './googleMaps.util';

describe('GoogleMapsUtil', () => {
  let util, $httpBackend, $document, $window: any;
  const options = {library: 'places', v: 3};
  beforeEach(inject((_$document_, _$httpBackend_, _$window_) => {
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    $document = _$document_;
    $window = _$window_;
    $httpBackend.when('GET', '^https:\/\/maps\.googleapis\.com\/maps\/api\/js.*').respond(200, {data: 'STUB RESPONSE'});
    util = new GoogleMapsUtil();
  }));

  afterEach(() => {
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
  });

  it('resolves the Google Maps library', () => {
    $httpBackend.expect('GET', '^https:\/\/maps\.googleapis\.com\/maps\/api\/js.*');
    return util.load(options).then((result) => {
      //WHAT TO DO HERE?
    });
  });
});
```

Currently also getting some error that seems to indicate my $httpBackend mock isn't working:

> Unsatisfied requests: GET ^https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js.*
>       verifyNoOutstandingExpectation

Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You are using the tags [tag:jasmine] and [tag:mocha] on your question, which suggests that your test is somehow running both in Jasmine and Mocha. In my experience people use one *or* the other but not both at the same time. If you are indeed using both simultaneously, please edit your question to detail the setup you are using. Otherwise, remove the tag that does not belong. (And edit the title too.)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I'm just running Mocha, not Jasmine.